# How to access a <select> value on page load with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show/hide elements based on the value of a `<select>` dropdown.

The select itself is made in symfony, like this:

```
$builder
->add('category')
```

And what I've done with jquery:

```
$('#resource_form_type_category').on('change', function () {
  $('.form-type-url').css('display', (this.value === '1' || this.value === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
  $('.form-type-image').css('display', (this.value === '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
  $('.form-type-file').css('display', (this.value === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

The problem here is the value isn't detected in this function when the page loads, leaving all elements visible until changing the select option.

I tried to bind load + change simultaneously but that didn't do anything.

I also know I can see the value on load with the `val()` function:

```
var selectedValue = $('#resource_form_type_category option:selected').val();
```

But I can't access the `selectValue` var inside my toggle function and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is the value isn't detected in this function when the page loads, leaving all elements visible until changing the select option

Obviously because you call the function only `on change` a workaround is:

```js
var myFancyFunction = function () {
    console.log(
        'jQuery value: '+ $(this).val() + '  <|> ',
        'vanilla javascript value: '+ this.value
    );
      $('.form-type-url').css('display', ($(this).val() === '1' || $(this).val() === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
      $('.form-type-image').css('display', ($(this).val() === '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
      $('.form-type-file').css('display', ($(this).val() === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
    };

    $('#resource_form_type_category').on('change', myFancyFunction);

    // now whenever your page is loaded you can call the myFancyFunction like
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // because we use $(this) or this inside myFancyFunction
        // we need to call the function like so from the outside:
        myFancyFunction.call($('#resource_form_type_category')[0]);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="resource_form_type_category">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="form-type-url"><h5>form-type-url</h5></div>
<div class="form-type-image"><h5>form-type-image</h5></div>
<div class="form-type-file"><h5>form-type-file</h5></div>
```

Comment: But a console.log(this.value) inside myFancyFunction still shows as undefined on page load and no field is shown on load, only when changing the selected value

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you for the update and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the same function to `change` event and run once on load separately.

```
$(function() {
    const formType = val => {
        $('.form-type-url').css('display', (val === '1' || val === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('.form-type-image').css('display', (val === '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('.form-type-file').css('display', (val === '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
    };

    formType($('#resource_form_type_category').val());

    $('#resource_form_type_category').change(function () {
        formType(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works too, but would you say this approach is better than the other answer?

Comment: I personally prefer using shorter and simpler codes as possible because of readability and maintainability. It’s just a preference. You can use either.